# Tomcat 7 manager Undeploy button disabled

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat 7 is installed on CentOS. Tomcat has two copies of application X running on it: two different hosts, two manager applications (each copied to webapps/Xn/manager). Applications work fine, Tomcat manager UI works fine except that `Undeploy` button is inactive/disabled. No errors in `catalina.out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/psi-probe/psi-probe/issues/374#issuecomment-81738169

> I think this bug can be closed. I just received this from a tomcat
>   maintainer:
>
> "By design, if a Context is defined in server.xml then that context is
>   excluded from the auto deployment process so neither an xml file in
>   the config base nor an XML file in the WAR (or a directory) is
>   considered."
>
> So, from this, I am guessing that apps cant be autodeployed.

Also when attempting to undeploy app via URL

```
FAIL - Context /my-app is defined in server.xml and may not be undeployed
```